Cython : How to import C++ struct to Cython Interface for both .pxd and pyx file
So I have this Person class which takes 3 parameters job as _Job struct, location as _Location pointer  and id as int. This class also has Getter and Setter as below
Person.h
struct _Location
{
    std::string country;
    int postal_number;

    _Location(std::string country, int postal_number) : country(country), postal_number(postal_number) {}
};

struct _Job
{
    std::string field;
    float salary;

    _Job(std::string field, float salary) : field(field), salary(salary) {}
};

class Person
{
private:
    _Job job;
    std::shared_ptr<_Location> location;
    int id;

public:
    Person(_Job job, std::shared_ptr<_Location> location, int id);

    std::shared_ptr<_Location> get_location();
    _Job get_job();

    void set_job(_Job new_job);
    void set_location(std::shared_ptr<_Location> new_location);
};

Now I want to import these features to Cython interface - Person.pxd and Person.pyx.
I think I know how to write the pxd code pretty well but the problem is the pyx code.
Person.pxd
cdef extern from "Person.h":
    cdef struct _Location:
        string country
        int postal_number;

        _Location(string country, int postal_number)

    cdef struct _Job:
        string field
        float salary;

        _Location(string field, float salary)

    cdef cppclass _Person "Person":
        _Person(shared_ptr[_Location] location, _Job job, int id)

        shared_ptr[_Location] get_location()
        _Job get_job()

        void set_location(shared_ptr[_Location] new_location)
        void set_job(_Job job)

cdef class Person:
    cdef shared_ptr[_Person] thisptr

Person.pyx
# 1. How do I get my _Location  & _Job struct in here?
# 2. How do I implement pointer and non_pointer struct?
# 3. Please help me out with my Constructor, Getter and Setter
cdef class Person:
    def __cinit__(self, location, job, id):
        self.thisptr = make_shared[_Person](...)  # FIX ME

    def __dealloc__(self):
        self.thisptr.reset()
        
    def get_location(self):
        # FIX ME
        pass

    def get_job(self):
        # FIX ME
        pass
    
    def set_location(self, new_location):
        # FIX ME
        pass
    
    def set_job(self, new_job):
        # FIX ME
        pass 

Please kindly help me out with Cython. Thank you.
